# Push to another ViewController

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

I have an issue with pushing to another view controller. I created a simple login system but the problem is even if the password is wrong it pushes me to the default view controller.

```
import UIKit
import Parse

class ViewController: UIViewController {

@IBOutlet weak var usernameTextField: UITextField!
@IBOutlet weak var passwordTextField: UITextField!

func createAlert(title: String, message: String) {

    let alert = UIAlertController(title: title, message: message, preferredStyle: UIAlertControllerStyle.alert)

    alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: .default, handler: { (alert) in

    }))
    self.present(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)

}

@IBAction func loginButton(_ sender: Any) {

    // ************ Login Page ************

    // Username error checking

    if usernameTextField.text == "" {

        let usernameAlert = UIAlertController(title: "Username is missing", message: "Please enter your username", preferredStyle: UIAlertControllerStyle.alert)

        usernameAlert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: .default, handler: { (action) in
            }))
        self.present(usernameAlert, animated: true, completion: nil)

        // Password error checking

    } else {

        if passwordTextField.text == "" {

            let passwordAlert = UIAlertController(title: "Passwors is missing", message: "Please enter your password", preferredStyle: UIAlertControllerStyle.alert)

            passwordAlert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: .default, handler: { (action) in
                self.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
            }))
            self.present(passwordAlert, animated: true, completion: nil)            }

        else {

        PFUser.logInWithUsername(inBackground: usernameTextField.text!, password: passwordTextField.text!, block: { (user, error) in

            if error != nil {



                var displayErrorMessage = "Please try again later."

                if let errorMessage = error as NSError? {

                    displayErrorMessage = errorMessage.userInfo["error"] as! String

                }


                self.createAlert(title: "Login Error", message: displayErrorMessage)
            } else {

                print ("Logged in")

                let storyBoard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)

                let cameraVC = storyBoard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "CameraViewController") as! CameraViewController

                self.navigationController?.pushViewController(cameraVC, animated: true)

            }
            })
        }
    }

}
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.



        }

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}
}
```

Note: when the username and password are valid I got "logged in" message in the debug area.

Comment: You added segue in storyboard? and post your all code.

Comment: @Abdullah show more code.

Comment: remove the connection from button and add the segue to class

Comment: Show code in login button action.

Comment: Yes I did make a segue from login button to the CameraViewController, it pushes me to it even if the password and username are wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

are you given the segue connection in direct button for e.g

[image]

> so it wont check the condition if you click the button it directly segue to another VC.

remove the connection between VC if you are using the storyboard ID, you can directly access

[image]

```
 let storyBoard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)

            let cameraVC = storyBoard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "CameraViewController") as! CameraViewController

            self.navigationController?.pushViewController(cameraVC, animated: true)
```

else

> connection oriented segue using direclty class

[image]

```
 [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"identifierName" sender:self];
```

call like

```
else {

            print ("Logged in")
            performSegue(withIdentifier: "identifierName", sender: self)

            }
```

Comment: Works like charm! 
Note: performSegue(withIdentifier: "identifierName", sender: self) should be self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "identifierName", sender: self)

Thank you guys so much!

Answer (score 0):

It' better if you use segue. First create a segue to CameraViewController with an identifier. Then,call it in coding.

performSegue(withIdentifier: "mySegueID", sender: self)

Answer (score 0):

1) Simple remove your code from IBAction target from storyboard.

2) Select your segue in storyboard -> Properties -> identifier -> set one identifier here.

3) Add this delegate in your code.

```
  override func shouldPerformSegue(withIdentifier identifier: String, sender: Any?) -> Bool {
        if  identifier == "youridentifier" {
            if username and password correct
            {
                return true
            }
            else
            {
                show alert here
                return 
            }
        }
        return true
    }
```

Simple!